# on Which Activity background I should display progress dialog when user can navigate to different activity based on his data in server

Tags: android

In my app I am creating Log in mechanism.In this when user enter username and password then in background data is fetch.On the basis on this fetched data user can navigate to different activity.Like if user is registered,if user not registered,if username and password is incorrect.

I have implememnt all this functionality.But here I am displaying progress dialog on the login Activity and then I navigate the user based on condition satisfied.But as the data is large hence activity layout taking more time to load and I have already dismiss the dialog in onPostMethod of AsyncTask.

So for 2-3 sec login activity is standstill without dialog(as it is already dismiss)
Hence where should I display the log in progress dialog.

Please tell me if any other detail is needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would take the route of checking whether or not you will still be using the Dialog UI component based upon the response.  And if it involves a task that will take some time to accomplish, I wouldn't dismiss the ProgressDialog at that moment.

I would wait until the operation completes in your follow up Activity and then dismiss it there.  Not sure what else we can as a community offer as a solution without any code or direct issues.  We can probably just speculate and come up with architectural/structural responses.

Answer (score 0):

Process all data in `doInBackground` in `onPostExecute` just navigate to new activity. for checking is user registered or not etc use some flag in `doInBackground` method.

Answer (score 0):

Dismiss the progressDialog immediatly ofter your startActivity() call.
*Make sure you dismiss it in the UI Thread.

I'm working in mono for android c# and my code will look like this (just change it to java):

```
 var myIntent = new Intent(this, typeof (MyActivity));


 StartActivity(myIntent);
 _progressDialog.Dismiss();
```

Comment: Means I have to dismiss dialog after startActivity(myintent).If I do this then dialog remains hang in my emulator for some time while myintent activity loads.